# Why is the antiderivative equal to $F(x)=|x|-1$

Tags: analysis

We have:

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
-1, & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\ 
1, & 0<x \leq 1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Why is the antiderivative equal to $F(x)=|x|-1$?

Do we have to find the integral of $f$ at both intervals? But... what limitsa of integration do we have to use??

**EDIT:**
In my notes,there is the remark,that if:

$$f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \text{ intergable }$$
$$F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$F(x)=\int_a^x f$$
$$F'(x_0)=f(x_0), \text{ ONLY IF } x_0: \text{ point at which f is continuous }$$

As a counter-example,they give the function:

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
-1, & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\ 
1, & 0<x \leq 1 
\end{matrix}\right.$
that is discontinuous at $0$,and then $F(x)=|x|-1$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: The function $F(x)$ has the right derivative (except of course at $0$). There are others. I suspect you are not giving the full problem, which likely involves a *definite* integral.

Comment: We cannot find an antiderivative $F$,that is differentiable at $0$,because $f$ is not continuous at this point,right??

Comment: @evinda: Your argumentation is completely wrong. Of course a differentiable function is continuous, however that doesn't imply that a differentiable function has continuous derivative...

Comment: Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: Derivatives need not be continuous, so one cannot call the fact that $f$ is not continuous the reason. A fancy reason is that derivatives have the Intermediate Value property, which $f$ doesn't.   A more basic reason is that the left and right limits of $f$ **exist** but are unequal. In a derivative, if the left and right limits exist, they must be equal.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I understand...thank you very much!!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $F(x)=|x|-1$.  If $-1\leq x<0$ then $F(x)=-x-1$.  So the derivative of $F$ is $-1$ on $[-1,0)$.  If $0<x\leq 1$ then $F(x)=x-1$.  So the derivative of $F$ is $1$ on $(0,1]$.

We have shown $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$, i.e., $F$ is *an* antiderivative of $f$. Note that there may be others, such as simply $|x|$, or more generally $|x|+C$ for any $C\in \mathbb R$.  As a consequence of the Mean Value Theorem, $|x|+C$ $C\in\mathbb R$ is the *most general* form that an antiderivative of $f$ can have.

Edit: If you include $0$ in the domain of $f$, then since $F$ is not differentiable at $0$, I would be inclined to say $F$ is not an antiderivative of $f$.  However, if you only require that $F$ satisfy $F'(x)=f(x)$ where $f$ is continuous, $F$ still works, as $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Tom Cruise: Nice,I understand... So,we cannot find an antiderivative $F$ in a domain that includes also $0$,right??

Comment: Correct. An antiderivative $F$ would have to be essentially $|x|$ on $[-1,0)\cup (0,1]$.  To be differentiable at $0$ it would have to be continuous at $0$, meaning $F(0)$ completes the "V" shape.  So $F$ would be $|x|$, which is not differentiable at $0$!

Comment: A ok...thanks!!!